# symfony2: Allow cronjob to access fosuserbundle protected controller actions

Tags: php, symfony, cron, fosuserbundle

I am building a tool which requires several different background tasks. They are accessible by logged in users, since it should be possible to trigger them from the browser as well. Also, they are spread out over different bundles.

For example:

- browse to `/x/backgroundtask` triggers `xBundle/controller`'s `backgroundtaskAction`
- browse to `/yBundle/backgroundTask` `yBundle/controller`'s `backgroundtaskAction`

I have a task entity, with a sql table storing frequencies, the last time a task is executed and URL's for each background task.

Basically what I want is one controller action in a `taskBundle`, checking which tasks should be performed based on frequency and last execution. This leads to my question:

All background task actions are protected by `FosUserBundle`. How do I make sure a cronjob task has access anyway? I can detect cronjobs by using php's `php_sapi_name()` function. Is there a way to auto-login for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the cron server IP to security.yml so It doesn't login.

security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        #
        - { path: ^/url, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, serverIP-Here, ::1] }